# iOS App Store link don't work in Flutter url_launcher

Tags: ios, flutter, url-launcher

I am using url_launcher in my flutter app to open an app in iOS App Store, in ios device
Url: https://apps.apple.com/se/app/instagram/id389801252

I enabled `mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication` to launch the app directly in App Store, it worked before but not now.
launchUrl return false. and same function works well in Android devices but not in iOS

```
 if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      if(externalNonBrowserApplication == true){ 
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication);
      }
      else {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url)); 
      }
    } else {
      print('Could not launch $url');
    }
```

Flutter version: 3.3.4
url_launcher: 6.1.6
ios: 16

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher

Comment: I don't want to use another package because url_launcher works well in android but not any more in ios devices with externalNonBrowserApplication = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue in iOS devices by adding `externalApplication` and `externalNonBrowserApplication` for Android devices

`await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);`